# Viewshed calculation throws "ERROR 010462: Geodesic visibility exception:"

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, viewshed

I'm trying to calculate the viewshed from a given point on the top of a building and I'm using the following line:

```
VS2 = Viewshed2(DSM_model, 'fl_Opt_Prospect', VS2_agl_raster, 'FREQUENCY', refractivity_coefficient=0.13, surface_offset=0, observer_offset='OFFSETA', outer_radius='RADIUS2', outer_radius_is_3d='3D', horizontal_start_angle='AZIMUTH1', horizontal_end_angle='AZIMUTH2', vertical_upper_angle='VERT1', vertical_lower_angle='VERT2', analysis_method="PERIMETER_SIGHTLINES")
```

It works fine only for certain values of RADIUS2. If RADIUS2 is 1800 metres for example, it works fine. 1900 metres and above it gives me the following error:

*ERROR 010462: Geodesic visibility exception: write failure: C:\Users\OPTIMT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ArcGISPro11624\_vs_{66AAE8BB-9549-4CF7-9E09-1E8937DE4C84}116243372.tmp*

Comment: have you seen this discussion? https://community.esri.com/thread/159818

Comment: I have set TdrDelay up to 60 and it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the Viewshed2 tool generates huge temporary files on disk during its execution, so make sure you have plenty of disk space. I've also had the same error (specifically the "write failure" error) when running larger coverages, even with 30 GiB of free space.